# Proof of Bolzano-Weierstrass for functions over countable domains

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Theorem** *A bounded sequence of functions defined over a countable domain has a convergent subsequence.*

The attempted proof uses Bolzano-Weierstrass  for real sequences (nested bisections) proof and a diagonal construction.

**Attempted Proof:**

> Let  $f_n$ denote a sequence of functions, where each function is defined over same countable domain $A = \{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_m\}$. Let $|f_n(x)| \leq M$ for any $x \in A$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> Evalute each function of the sequence at $x_1 \in A$ to obtain a sequence ${\large(}f_{n}(x_1){\large)}: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which is bounded by assumption.
>
> Bisect the interval $[-M, M]$ and choose the half with infinite number of points.  Continuing with this process, we obtain a family of nested closed intervals $I_{k+1} \subseteq I_k$.

This is basically Bolzano-Weierstrass for real sequences, but the point of redoing the proof is to be able to construct, in addition to the subsequence of real numbers, a corresponding subsequence of functions.

> Choose at each bisection step $f_{k}(x_1) \in I_k \cap (f_n(x_1)) \subset \mathbb{R}$, and choose the corresponding function before evaluation $f_k \in (f_n)$. So that we obtain a subsequence of functions (denote it  by $(f_{1, k})$).

While it is intuitive that we can do the choice above, can we make this more formal? Do we need the axiom of choice for this argument?

> By the nested interval property of $\mathbb{R}$, there's $L \in \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n$ which is the limit of the subsequence $f_{1,k}(x_1)$, for we can find an $N$ such that the length of $I_N = M \frac{1}{2^{N}}$ gets smaller than $\epsilon$.
>
> For each subsequence $(f_{n,k})$ constructed from  $(f_{n-1,k})$ for being convergent when evaluated at $x_n$, apply same bisection argument to construct $(f_{n+1, k}) \subseteq (f_{n,k})$ convergent when evaluated at $x_{n+1}$ and at $x_{n}$.

We may then use a diagonal construction to obtain a subsequence as follows. Since

> $(f_{1, k}) = \mathbf{f_{1,1}}, f_{1,2}, f_{1,3}, \cdots$ converges when evaluated at $x_1$
>
> $\cup$
>
> $(f_{2, k}) = f_{2,1}, \mathbf{f_{2,2}}, f_{2,3}, \cdots$ converges when evaluated at $x_1$, $x_2$
>
> $\cup$
>
> $(f_{3, k}) = f_{3,1}, f_{3,2}, \mathbf{f_{3,3}}, \cdots$ converges when evaluated at $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$
>
> Let $(f'_k) = f_{1,1}, f_{2,2}, f_{3,3}, \cdots$. Evaluated at $x_n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it can be seen that all but a finite number of elements of $(f'_k)$, particularly elements of the form $f_{m,m}$ for $m \geq n$ are chosen from the sequence $(f_{n, k})$, which converges when evaluated at $x_n$ by construction. Hence $(f'_k)$ converges at $x_n$, and since $x_n$ was arbitrary, it converges at every point in A.